# How to call phtml page in cms block in home page?

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.8

how to call app\design\frontend\default\default\template\ma2_popuplogin\popuplogin.phtml url in cms block home page?
i tried below{{block template="frontend/base/default/template/asktologin/index.phtml"}}
but not working. kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

Magento knows that you're loooking in `frontend/...`, so you should be fine with defining the `type`, telling Magento that you want a simple block using a template, and only specifying the path from `template/`

```
{{block type="core/template" template="asktologin/index.phtml"}}
```